# Is there a tool like "Pex" that can do stress tests on WP7?

Tags: unit-testing, windows-phone-7

I'm a windows phone developer.

I found a very excellent tool **Silverlight Unit Test Framework** to do unit test.

But, I want to do some automated tests for each function by inputting random data (like stress test).

There is a tool called **[Pex](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/)** that can do that things for me, but it does not seems to support WP7 right now.

Is there a tool like **Pex** that can do stress tests on WP7?

Comment: Hi,

I am a developer from the Pex project. Unfortunately, Pex does not support Silverlight or Silverlight for Phone currently. We have no immediate plans to support this runtime in the short term.

You can post other questions on Pex at: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/pex/threads/.

Cheers, Peli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are currently no stress testing solutions for Windows Phone 7, see this related question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137528/ui-automation-for-wp7

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028566/is-ui-automation-possible-on-windowsphone7

Comment: Thanks for you reply ColinE. About this problem i have been found other way. Pex generated by SUTF project is a silverlight for windows version of the project, not silverlight for windows phone version of the project, so can not do windows phone OS-specific classes and api's test. If the pex can have an optional framework option is designed for windows phone developers choose, it would be great, but unfortunately so far not yet.